# Rails4; Where to put global constant accessed in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking for where to put **global constant** which can be accessed within the rails application.

I put secrets constants into `.env` file such as *secret key* or *password* for third party APIs.

However I wonder where to put global constants which are not really need to be hidden.

***For example; I've been building a payment_system***

```
DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 'month'.freeze
DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'us'.freeze
```

Where should I put those constant?

Any best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not change these constant often, you can have a class similar to following:

```
class DefaultSetting
  DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 'month'.freeze
  DEFAULT_CURRENCY = 'us'.freeze
End
```

Then you can reference those constant by `DefaultSetting::DEFAULT_INTERVAL`.

However, by having these as ENV variables (i.e in `.env`), you can change these values on the fly(without code-change/deployment).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This file should be in lib/default_setting.rb ?

Comment: I would put it in `/models` folder, because it feels to me those constants are part of business logic. I would put other 3rd party librarys/tools in `/lib` folder. Rails doc: `lib – Application specific libraries. Basically, any kind of custom code that doesn’t belong under controllers, models, or helpers. This directory is in the load path.` However,  either folder will technically work fine.

Comment: Thanks! For me I use service object, so business logic is there. So I'd go for  `lib/default_setting.rb`.